# Insert mode completion of executables in `$PATH` (like `compgen -c`)

Tags: autocompletion, external-command

When writing shell scripts, it is frequently necessary to call external commands in `$PATH`. Some of these have long names (e.g. `system-config-printer-applet` or `xfwm4-workspace-settings`), and it would be useful to be able to complete them while in insert mode. Shells like `bash` and `zsh` have this capability built in.

However, this isn't built into any of Vim's `ins-completion` defaults.

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#ins-completion

The feature was requested in 2004, but does not seem to have been implemented since then.

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.editors.vim/26022

Is there a setting or plugin to enable this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This recipe enables dictionary completion for shell scripts via regular keyword completion and omni completion:

1. Add the following lines to `~/.vimrc` to enable dictionary completion in shell scripts:

   ```
   augroup shellscripts
       " prevent duplicates if .vimrc is sourced twice.
       autocmd!

       " tell Vim where the dictionary is
       autocmd FileType sh setlocal complete+=k~/shellcmds.txt dictionary=~/shellcmds.txt

       " completions for hyphenated commands
       autocmd FileType sh setlocal iskeyword+=-

       " generate the dictionary
       autocmd FileType sh call system("compgen -c > ~/shellcmds.txt")
   augroup END
   ```
2. Open a shell script in a new Vim instance.
3. Press `<C-n>` (keyword completion) or `<C-x><C-k>` (omni completion) in insert mode to perform completion.

---

If you want to keep your `vimrc` lean and clean, you can move the important bits of the snippet above in a proper ftplugin.

The file:

```
~/.vim/after/ftplugin/sh.vim
```

Its content:

```
setlocal complete+=k~/shellcmds.txt
setlocal dictionary=~/shellcmds.txt
setlocal iskeyword+=-
silent call system("compgen -c > ~/shellcmds.txt")
```

---

Dictionary completion is a cheap and easy way to get completion for unsupported languages and frameworks.

Comment: Could you modify your answer to run `compgen` when the `.vimrc` is read?

Comment: Yeah, answer edited.

Comment: It works; the only thing I would add is `set iskeyword+=-` to complete hyphenated commands cleanly.